# Creating multiple dataframes in a loop in R

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, subset

I am new to R and I don't know how to create multiple data frames in a loop. For example:
I have a data frame "Data" with 20 rows and 4 columns:

```
Data <- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = 20, ncol = 4))
names(Data) <- c("A","B","C","D")
```

I want to choose the rows of Data which its values in column T are the closest values to the vector elements of X.

```
X = c(X1,X2,X3,X4,X5)
```

Finally, I want to assign them to a separate data frames with their associated X name:

```
for(i in 1:length(X)){ 
data_X[i] <- data.frame(matrix(NA))  
data_X[i] <- subset(data2, 0 <= A-X[i] | A-X[i]< 0.000001 )
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: There is no column 'T' in the eexample and the 'Data' showed is alll `NA` values

Comment: Oh, this is a typo akrun. The column "T" should be column "A"

Comment: ok, but still not clear how you are comparing `< 0.00001` when the values are all `NA`

Comment: Right, let’s ignore the NA and let’s assume the “Data” data frame has values in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't give us any numbers, it is difficult to say exactly what you need the for loop to look for. As such, you will need to sort that out yourself, but here is a basic example of what you could do. The important part that I think you are missing is that you need to use `assign` to send the created dataframes to your global environment or wherever you want them to go for that matter. `Paste0` is a handy way to give them each their own name. Take note that some of the data frames will be empty. It may be worthwhile to use an `if` statement that skips `assign`ing the dataframe `if (nrow(data3)==0)`.

```
`Data <- data.frame(matrix(sample(1:10,80,replace = T), nrow = 20, ncol = 4))`
`names(Data) <- c("A","B","C","D")`
`X = c(1:10)` 


`for(i in 1:length(X)){ 
  data2 <- Data 
  data3 <- subset(data2, A == X[i])
  assign(paste0("SubsetData",i), data3, envir = .GlobalEnv)
}`
```